# Can use app specific static files fine, cannot get static files under project root to load

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-2.2, django-static

So I have two apps (`account` and `job`). Each app has its own respective `app_name/templates/app_name` and `app_name/static/app_name` directories.

With the following static related settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

I can use app-specific templates and static files with no problem. I.e. in my `job/templates/index.html` I have the line

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'job/index.css' %}">`
```

and it grabbed the `job/static/job/index.css` file.

However, under the main project directory(`website/`) I have a `website/templates/base.html`( in other answers on here I have seen this where you should store `base.html`) and a `website/static/css/base.css` file . I cannot get this `base.css` file to load. Within `base.html` I have tried the following three links:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'base.css' %}">
   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'static/css/base.css' %}">
```

and none of them have worked. Does anyone know how to get this `base.css` working? Thanks in advance and yes I included `{% load static %}` and have ran `collectstatic`.

Update:
When I click 'source' in chrome dev tools I see the following directory layout:

```
static/
  css/
    base.css ("Could not find the original style sheet.")
  job/
    index.css (working without a problem)
```

also when I navigate directly to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/base.css` I get a page not found(404) error.

Comment: Have you tried running `manage.py collectstatic` command?

Comment: yes I ran that command and restarted server @n1rna